# MobileFirst APNS push notifications fails with java.net.SocketException (Connection closed by remote host)

Tags: java, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a MobileFirst application trying to send push with a production APNS certificate.

I get this exception when push is submitted :

```
    INFO: Failed to send message Message(Id=2; Token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"Blah blah blah","action-loc-key":null},"sound":"","badge":1},"payload":"{\"alias\":\"News_fr\",\"custom\":\"data\"}"})... trying again after delay
java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
        at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The server is running an Oracle JRE 1.7 and Tomcat 7 on Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy).
The MobileFirst version is 6.3.0.

It worked well with the development certificate.

I developed a standalone Java application (using JavAPNS instead of Notnoop) to reproduce the problem on my local environment with the same certificate and it worked with Java 1.6 but not higher.

Comment: Did you try in Tomcat with Java 1.6 then?

Comment: No, I did not try on Java 1.6 as it is a production environment and I do not have the privileges to install a new version of Java.
I wanted to confirm the problem comes from the Java version before asking to "downgrade" the Java version.

Comment: Do you not have a Pre-prod environment that you can change the installed Java version? (Dev > QA > UAT/Pre-prod > Prod). An environment that is just like the production environment, but for testing.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, and tell you if Java version is the problem here

Comment: I asked my Pre-production environment to be modified with Java 1.6.

Comment: It worked with my standaleone app and the MobileFirst server.
For me, there is a problem with MobileFirst on JRE 1.7 when sending push notifications to Apple in production mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PMR (support ticket) was opened for this issue, and it was decided by the customer to downgrade the installed Java to Oracle Java 1.6 after which sending push notifications successfully resumed.

Comment: Hi I have updated my push plugin after that i can able to register IOS device but notification not able to push because i can see the error in server logs, the socket exception throwing. why its different previous version vs current version ?  Product version: 8.0.0.00-20200121-1306.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I have also seen this *exact* error occur when `apns-certificate-sandbox.p12` was outdated or incorrectly generated. Following [these instructions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en) to regenerate that file (and redeploying the `.wlapp`) resolved the issue.